# Html not rendering in Email Client like Gmail

Tags: android, email, android-intent

> I am rendering HTML using Html.fromHtml and passed it to emailIntent.

```
                        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                                "mailto","", null));

                        ///emailIntent.setType("text/html");
                        emailTemplate = emailTemplate.replaceAll("(\r\n|\n)", "<br />").trim();

                        emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");

                        Spanned shareBody = null;//remove it's instance...

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                            Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(emailTemplate ,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
                            shareBody = spanned;
                            ///emailTemplate = spanned.toString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Spanned spanned =  Html.fromHtml(emailTemplate);
                            shareBody = spanned;
                            ///emailTemplate = spanned.toString();
                        }

                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);//emailTemplate);
                        mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

where emailTemplate is

```
"\u003ctable id=\"pltrlText\" style=\"width:100%; display:block; margin:0px; padding:0px;\"\u003e \u003ctbody style=\"display: block;\"\u003e \u003ctr style=\"display: block; margin: 0px 5px 30px 5px; \"\u003e \u003ctd style=\"font-family: \u0027OpenSansRegular\u0027, Arial; color: #444444; font-size: 14px; \"\u003e HI[Razi] \u003c/td\u003e \u003c/tr\u003e \u003ctr style=\"display: block; margin: 0px 5px 30px 5px; \"\u003e \u003ctd style=\"font-family: \u0027OpenSansRegular\u0027, Arial; color: #444444; font-size: 14px; \"\u003e We are happy to offer you solutions, that make a positive impact on your business. We are happy to offer you solutions, that make a positive impact on your business. We are happy to offer you solutions, that make a positive impact on your business. We are happy to offer you solutions, that make a positive impact on your business.We are happy to offer you solutions, that make a positive impact on your business. We are happy to offer you solutions, that make a positive impact on your business. \u003c/td\u003e \u003c/tr\u003e \u003c/tbody\u003e \u003c/table\u003e"
```

No next line shows for  and no style applied. What am I doing wrong. Also tried with String and Spanned.

**And no style is working like color and backgrounds**

> But same is working for IOS app gmail client and others too.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong...` You're converting the tag characters (`<`  and `>`) to their Unicode codes.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong.

You are assuming that you can use arbitrary HTML. Few email clients, on any platform (including Web mail), support arbitrary HTML in their email composers.

In the case of Android, in general, expect to be limited to the tags supported by `Html.fromHtml()` and `Html.toHtml()`. Of note, given your very strange template:

- `<table>` is not supported (along with `<tr>` and `<td>`)
- Most of your `style` bits are not supported

Comment: But same is working for IOS app gmail client and others too.

Comment: @Nepster: iOS is not Android.